# How to get imageurl from the url? So it can show the image I want in the page

Tags: php, image, url, imageurl

So I have this page .html , .php, whatever, It's a page with my logo, some ads, menus etc.
I want this page to show the image I want, Let's say I have /images/image1.jpg and I want to sent it to someone, but I want that person to see it in my website so I would so something like
mypage.com/example.php(somecodehere?)/images/image1.jpg

And it would open example.php (or .html) with image1.jpg displaying where I had my code (let's say in the middle)

Any simple way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the $_GET to get the image:

```
www.exapmle.com/page.php?imagename=image1.jpg => simple example for the page.php code
<?php
   echo "<img src=\"{$_GET["imagename"]}\">";
?>
```

Be aware that this is a dangerous code and you should always check the input from the user.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $_GET[] in order to get the image path. Lets say that your link is:

```
http://blabla.com/example.php?img=image1.jpg
```

Now, you need to get that img value:

```
$img = $_GET["img"];
```

Now you have the image that you want to display :)

Answer (score 0):

So, from my understanding you have an images hosted on your website that you wish to share with people via a link of some sort?

If so, the best way to do this is would be via GET variables.
For example, if you had an image called : holiday.jpg, the link would be:

http://domain.com/example.php?img=holiday.jpg

Therefore within your web page example.php (must have the .php ext) you would have something along the lines of :

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>IMG SITE</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
     <?php
     if(isset($_GET["img"])) echo '<img src="/images/directory/'.$_GET["img"].'">';
     ?>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Note

Be careful not to have slashes in your GET variable eg: /image/directory/holiday.jpg . Properly escape this by replace dashes with %2F